# Why Java HttpClient in Scala 2.13 requires JVM parameter "--add-exports"

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt, openjdk-11

we have a Scala (2.13.8) project where we use the `java.net.http.HttpClient` to resolve a simple Rest call.

Until the project was built using SBT there was no issue. Since we moved to Maven, we are encountering the following runtime error:

```scala
cannot access class jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestBuilderImpl (in module java.net.http) because module java.net.http does not export jdk.internal.net.http to unnamed module
```

Since we create a fat-jar out of the project, we managed to solve the issue passing the following additional parameter to the CLI command:

```bash
java --add-exports java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http=ALL-UNNAMED -jar abc.jar
```

The reason why we moved back to Maven was due to issues in handling Log4j2 with the SBT build. Now in Maven we are using the `scala-maven-plugin` as following:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <scalaVersion>2.13.8</scalaVersion>
    <args>
      <arg>-language:higherKinds</arg>
      <arg>-explaintypes</arg>
      <arg>-deprecation</arg>
      <!-- optimizations -->
      <arg>-optimize</arg>
      <arg>-opt:unreachable-code</arg>
      <arg>-opt:box-unbox</arg>
      <arg>-opt:l:inline</arg>
      <arg>-opt-inline-from:**</arg>
      <arg>-target:11</arg>
    </args>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

What are we doing wrong compared to the working out-of-the-box SBT build where everything was working just fine (not even targeting the specific JDK 11)? In that case there was no need of `--add-exports` parameter, and everything could run also from IntelliJ directly (now we can's).

*p.s.
Before you redirect me to other posts, IntelliJ is already configured to target the JDK 11 and use the SDK 11 in the whole project (and also general settings).*

Thank you in advance for any clarification.

Comment: "Since we create a fat-jar out of the project". The process that creates the fat JAR might throw away some module-info.java files that might cause this. Not sure, but you should check that.

Comment: As mentioned towards the end, the runtime error occurs also when we run directly from IntelliJ - it was not the case when using SBT.

Comment: Consider adding a simple way to reproduce your issue.